# Java as Windows service using visual basic script and batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, permissions, jvm

I'm trying to initialize a Java service using a Visual Basic script located in startup folder. This vbs script calls a batch file which is in the same folder as the jar I want to initialize. The batch calls the jar with the propers arguments and it works fine but when I call the batch file from vbs jumps an error:

[image: Windows error]

I guess it's a security problem but I don't know how solve it.

- The folder for vbs is: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
- Content vbs:

```vb
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """C:\Program Files\Res\run_res.bat""", 0, True
```

- The folder for batch and jar is: C:\Program Files\Res\
- Content batch:

```
javaw -jar dpc.jar
```

Comment: I really don't see the reason for using a Visual Basic script interpreted by Windows Script Host running a batch file interpreted by Windows command processor to run the executable `javaw.exe`. Why do you not create in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` a shortcut (file with extension .lnk) which has configured in __Properties__ (right click on created shortcut to see that context menu item) for the property __Target__ `"C:\Full Path to\javaw.exe" -jar dpc.jar` and for the property __Start in__ the full path of the directory containing file `dpc.jar`?

Comment: Windows would run Java with such a shortcut in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` directly without running first `wscript.exe` (Windows GUI version) or `cscript.exe` (Windows console version) of Windows Script Host depending on what is currently configured as default to run `cmd.exe` to run `javaw.exe`. It looks like you have chosen this solution because of not knowing that any executable can be started directly by Windows with a shortcut put on Windows desktop, or somewhere in Windows start menu or wherever you want to create and use a Windows shortcut file.

Comment: I haven't thought in this solution but it's better than mine for sure. I will implement it in your way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was running vbs from another folder I needed to specify the entire absolute path of the jar in the batch.